# Intellij Java version

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can somebody tell me what are all the places where I have to change the java version, because I have changed it in more than 5 places so far (I don't even remember all of them) and it is still saying "diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5". The most stupid ide ever..

1. Project -> Project SDK
2. Project -> Project language level
3. Modules -> Language level
4. Project bytecode version
5. Target bytecode version

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: Maybe, *just* maybe if a wildly popular tool isn't doing what you want it to it's not because it's stupid.

Comment: Just two places: Project and Module.  Dumbest?  Hardly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use *Maven* in IntelliJ IDEA to build your project you have to set Java version as parameters `source` and `target` in configuration for `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Default version for this is 1.5 and IDE use it to check source code compatibility.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the problem